# Uncaught exception when sending from my Fault sequence to an endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am getting an `Uncaught exception java.lang.ClassCastException: ...` when trying to send message from my Fault sequence to an endpoint in WSO2 ESB 4.8.1.

Below is the Error stack:

```
[2015-08-21 12:15:01,298] ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPFault
            at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPBodyImpl.getFault(SOAPBodyImpl.java:120)
            at org.apache.synapse.util.MessageHelper.cloneSOAPEnvelope(MessageHelper.java:383)
            at org.apache.synapse.util.MessageHelper.cloneAxis2MessageContext(MessageHelper.java:233)
            at org.apache.synapse.util.MessageHelper.cloneMessageContext(MessageHelper.java:86)
            at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CalloutMediator.mediate(CalloutMediator.java:144)
            at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
            at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
            at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
            at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler.onFault(MediatorFaultHandler.java:85)
            at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:54)
            at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.invokeNextFaultHandler(AbstractEndpoint.java :640)
            at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.onFault(AbstractEndpoint.java:475)
            at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.onFault(AddressEndpoint.java:43)
            at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:102)
            at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:435)
            at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java :170)
            at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
            at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:225)
            at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: When this occurs, is the backend sending a SOAP fault to esb?

Comment: No,  I guess it is unable to form the SOAP Fault, hence the message

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Try do aplly this patch https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SYNAPSE-883 maybe will help you.

If this issue is a really bug try to change `Callout Mediator` to `Send Mediator`.

Comment: Could you merge your answers? Moreover, if you wish to improve your answer, could you describe the reason why it may solve the problem?